# SVG Mask with Multiple Video sources?

Tags: css, svg, mask

Not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to see if it is possible to have an SVG circle mask for different video DOM elements that will all be fixed.

[image]

Ideally, each SVG circle above will mask a video that will be in a different layer.  Then I would transform the circle to scale up to fit the browser height/width

I've tried all different code samples, so putting code here won't really do any difference, just looking for a direction to see if this is technically possible, and to put me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, you can use `clip-path` for that, like this:

```
video {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  clip-path: circle(20%);
}

video.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/deaxfcbk/

Open the example linked above and click on a video, it will fill the result area keeping its proportions and the other videos will be hidden. If you click again it will become a circle.

You can add as many videos as you want to, hide controls, play them on full screen, etc.

Hope this help :)